# which element contains #id idString return index

Tags: javascript, jquery

Multiple elements with "column" class.
Find which column element contains a id: idString, return index of the !column! that contains the id

This is the new (3rd) html I am searching:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
    <meta name="generator" content="Amazon.com">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style type="text/css" class="dontsplit">       .column *{ padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="calibre" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 101024px;">
<div class="calibre67">
    <div class="last first column" style="width: 616px; float: left;">
        <p class="calibre2" style="padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px;">
            <span class="calibre3">bla , bla etc.</span> 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="width: 616px; float: left;">
        <div class="calibre1 split">
            <p class="calibre2" style="padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px;">
                <span class="calibre3">bla bla etc.</span> 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- div contains the ID I want to find, structure of page varies with different files -->
    <div class="column" style="width: 616px; float: left;">
        <div class="calibre1 split">
            </p>
            <p class="calibre4" style="padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px;">
<!-- This is the id I want to find, so the function should return 2 (3rd column).  -->
                <span id="1P-09761e033cf14df8aeccf069ebe7886e" class="calibre6">Prologue:</span> 
            </p>
            <p class="calibre5" style="padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px;">
                <span class="calibre6">It had been bla, bla etc.</span> 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Code:

```
var idString = "O-09761e033cf14df8aeccf069ebe7886e";

function findID(idString) {
    $(".column").each(function(index, element){
                if ($(this).find('*').attr('id') == idString) {
                        console.log(index);
                        return index;
                }
    });
    return;
}

var result = findID(idString);

// should return/log 2
// currently returns/logs nothing
```

Function should return 2 in this example.
I have tried very many combinations of your suggestions.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if ($(idString)) {` is always true because `$()` always returns an object, and objects are  truethy.

Comment: And also the `$()` isn’t being scoped to the element — it’s just a global search for the id on the page.

Comment: @Louys, @ObsidianAge, I tried your suggestions but they do not return any result with the "New"(3rd!, sorry) HTML. I probably do not select/search for the correct element but I can not find any slution on the net. Tried: `if ($(this).find('*').attr('id') == idString)` and `if ($("[id='idString']")` and many, many more. No result. Would you be so kind to look at my question again? Thanks.

Comment: @Louys, @ObsidianAge, I am looking for something like this. This works as expected: returns column index first time text is found. `function findTextInColumns(string) {
    $(".column").filter(function(index){
                        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                        return index; // Found!
                        }
                        });
    return; // Not Found!
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if ($idString)` will always return `true`. Instead of that check, you'll want to check against the **[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** of each element with `if ($(this).attr('id') == idString)`.

Note that the attribute doesn't actually contain the `#`, so you'll want to remove the `#` from the ID variable, or make use of **[`.contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)**.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var idString = "O-09761e033cf14df8aeccf069ebe7886e";

function findID(idString) {
  $(".column").each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == idString) {
      console.log(index);
      return index;
    }
  });
  return;
}

findID(idString);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="column">“When the grav emitters are charged"</p>
<p class="column">“It wasn’t that bad this time”</p>
<p class="column" id="O-09761e033cf14df8aeccf069ebe7886e">Chapter 1</p>
<p class="column">“I can monitor engineering from up here”</p>
```

Also note that the index is zero-based.

Comment: You might want to mention that the index is zero-based. It is nicer (when dealing with obvious homework questions) to tell the user where he went wrong, and what they didn't include, and suggest how to fix - without providing the full answer. Otherwise, very nice answer.

Comment: Based on the question, it seems as though the user is aware that it is zero based.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer. I made a mistake in my question: The id is nested in a .column in a "p". Could you look at my question again?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery [`.index(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method. It will return the index of the matched element *(on the left hand side)* within the collection of the selector on the right hand side.

> A selector representing a jQuery collection in which to look for an element.

```js
var idString = "#O-09761e033cf14df8aeccf069ebe7886e";

function findID(idToSearch) {
    return $(idToSearch).index(".column p");
}

var result = findID(idString);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="column">
<p>“When the grav emitters are charged"</p>
</div>

<div class="column">
<p>“When the grav emitters are charged"</p>
</div>

<div class="column">
<p id="O-09761e033cf14df8aeccf069ebe7886e">Chapter 1</p>
<p>“I can monitor engineering from up here”</p>
</div>

<div class="column">
<p>“When the grav emitters are charged"</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Very clean approach, without explicit loops or re-wrapping elements.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer. I made a mistake in my question: The id is nested in a .column in a "p". Could you look at my question again?

Comment: This is not a big change... On the right hand side, add the `p` in the selector. I updated my answer with your HTML markup.